# WooCommerce Credit Card Form support

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, credit-card

I'm not a programmer, and I need your help about WooCommerce Credit Card Form on my WordPress site.

I use a 2Checkout Payment plugin at Github
to let my customers checkout via Credit Card directly on my website. The plugin works well.

Here is my Credit Form: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ7Av.png)

How can I add a function that auto detect card type like this guy: [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEz7l.png)

Comment: You can scan the numbers to check the card type and then display an image at the end of the textbox. Each card has a definite pattern all you need to do is to check it. @TiEl

Comment: Thank you @ Abhishek V Ashok to help. But can you show me the code? I'm not a coder, and I do not know how to do this.

Comment: What is the id of the textbox i mean the credit card number box? @TiEl

Comment: @  Abhishek V Ashok: The ID of the textbox is "ccNo":

<input type="text" class="input-text wc-credit-card-form-card-number" id="ccNo" autocomplete="cc-number" placeholder="•••• •••• •••• ••••" value="">

Comment: OK can you give what all cards you need to support? Maybe mail it to me at: abishekvashok@gmail.com @TiEl